# How do I pause this thread after x minutes

Tags: python, multithreading, bots, python-multithreading

How to pause this thread from running every 300 seconds for 500 seconds? I need to suspend it from running all the functions every x minutes to prevent API breaches. Timer objects seem to only start the code, whereas the objective is to pause, wait, resume.

```
from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
from threading import Thread
import random

my_bot = TwitterBot()
my_bot.sync_follows()


def a():
    my_bot.auto_fav("@asco", count=1000)

def b():
    my_bot.auto_fav("ATSO", count=1000)

def c():
    my_bot.auto_fav("BCY3", count=1000)

lof = [a, b, c]
random.shuffle(lof)

for z in lof:
    Thread(target=z).start()
```

Credit to @Farhan.K for assisting with the code.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: This seems to only start the code. I need to interrupt it, wait, and resume. Did I misunderstand the documentation?

Comment: You can't pause threads. Code in the thread may be able to pause themselves but I guess that would be a question about the `TwitterBot` API and not about threading.

Comment: You could subclass `TwitterBot` and override [wait_on_action](https://github.com/rhiever/TwitterFollowBot/blob/master/TwitterFollowBot/__init__.py#L47) to use a custom sleep duration pattern (if the FOLLOW_BACKOFF_MIN_SECONDS and FOLLOW_BACKOFF_MAX_SECONDS options are not enough for your use case).

Comment: @nomadictype Thank you for the insight. Will explore subclass usage.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this for your threads?

```
import time


def sleep_thread(sleepWait, sleepTime):
    timeStart = time.time()
    timeElapsed = 0 

    while timeElapsed <= sleepWait:
        timeElapsed = time.time() - timeStart
        print 'time elapsed = ' + str(timeElapsed)
        time.sleep(1)

    print 'going to sleep. zzz....'
    # Sleep for x 
    time.sleep(sleepTime)
    print 'im awake!'


sleep_thread(5, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, if I include it in the thread it only sleeps itself without effecting other threads. This is very helpful for something else I was doing.